# The world where every sequence is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, equivalence-relations

One day, I thougth "If every sequence is convergent, it is very nice." So I tried to define some equivalence class on the set of sequences. And I also tried to define operations such as addition, multiplication, etc, and the limit of the sequence of the "limit of the sequence". I also tried to extend the function to the "limit of the seauence".

But this is a very naive idea. And I could not go further with this idea.

Is there any work on this topic? That is, a work to define the limit for every sequence.

Please tell me any information.

Edit:

I try to clarify the idea. I would like to make a superset of numbers (let it denote S) which has some favorable properties. They may include the following:

(1) S is a vector space. If possible, a ring or a field.

(2) The sequences of S have a (linear?) operation called "limit". For number sequences, that operation is the same as the usual limit.

(3) If possible, the function of numbers can be extended to the function of S.

Comment: If $a \neq b$, what do you propose as the limit of the sequence $a,b,a,b,a,b,\ldots$? What about the sequence $b,a,b,a,b,a,\ldots$?

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is "topology". On any space equipped with the chaotic (or indiscrete) topology, every sequence converges to every point in the space at the same time. It's of little interest, since it's so unnatural. It's mainly a source of counter-examples.

Comment: What you are looking for is called an ultralimit. If you fix a non-prinipal ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$, then every bounded sequence of real numbers would have unique limit. Unbounded sequences like $1,2,3,...$ would have infinite ultralimit.

Comment: If every sequence is convergent, why exactly is that “nice” ?

Comment: @AdamRubinson: It is very nice and useful when one considers, for example, limits of metric spaces. Gromov-Hausdorff and others.

Comment: @JimmyK454 Maybe their limits are not numbers. Maybe not infinite, either. Maybe lim(a, b, a, b, ...) and lim(b, a, b, a, ...) are not equal. My first motivation was to make a superset of numbers whose sequences are close under a (linear?) operation called "limit".

Comment: @Ivo Terek Thank you for your comment. I think that topology is one way to solve the problem. But chaotic topology seems too "extreme" or "special" for me.

Comment: @markvs Thank you for your comment. I did not know the concept of ultralimit. I searched it and feel it interesting.

Comment: Many people found it ineresting.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a set. Equip $X$ with the trivial topology (consisting of only empty set and the set $X$). Every sequence in $X$ converges to each point in $X$. This is because if $x\in X$ and $(x_n)_n$ is a sequence in $X$, then the only open set containing $X$ must be $X$ itself!  Obviously all the terms in the sequence are in $X$.